# Weird syntax error (Java)

Tags: java

```
public int[][] fileRead(String fileName);
{
  Scanner problem = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
  int m = 9; 
  int [][] tgrid = new int[m][m]; 
  while(input.hasNextInt()){
    for (int i=0;i<m;i++){
      for (int j=0;j<m;j++)
        a[i][j] = input.nextInt();
    }
  }
```

For some reason this code is giving two syntax errors... The errors are as below.

```
2 errors found:
File: C:\Documents and Settings\s2813788\My Documents\Downloads\1005ICTAssignment\SudokuDriver.java  [line: 81]
Error: Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
File: C:\Documents and Settings\s2813788\My  Documents\Downloads\1005ICTAssignment\SudokuDriver.java  [line: 81]
Error: Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
```

I don't see anything wrong with the method header or anything like that :| Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can  you tell as what line is line 81?

Comment: public int[][] fileRead(String fileName)

Comment: @Ben Gittins Post your full function source ,in this code we could see the right curly braces were also missing for function ending statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a semicolon after your method arguments.

```
public int[][] fileRead(String fileName);
{
```

Remove it:

```
public int[][] fileRead(String fileName)
{
```

Comment: +1 also method's last curly brace is remaining, no return statement

Comment: `code` public int[][] fileRead(String fileName)
    {
      Scanner problem = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
      int m = 9; 
      int [][] tgrid = new int[m][m]; 
      while(input.hasNextInt()){
        for (int i=0;i<m;i++){
          for (int j=0;j<m;j++)
            a[i][j] = input.nextInt();
        }
      }
  return grid;
} `code`

Comment: 81. The declaration public int[][] fileRead(String fileName)

Comment: There is no issue there (unless you still need to remove the semicolon).  Are you sure it isn't the result of a missing bracket earlier in your code?

Comment: No have been through and checked the missing brackets there aren't any open brackets. Has left me quite stumped :S

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mT41y5R6 That's the rest of the code. Line of the errors is 81

Comment: @BenGittins You are declaring your `fileRead` method *within* your `main` method, causing the errors you see.  Close the `main` method before you declare and define `fileRead`, or place the `fileRead` method outside of the `main` method.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the semicolon at the end of the first line:

```
public int[][] fileRead(String fileName);
----------------------------------------^
```

Also make sure all previous functions are closed. Where is the ending `}` for the `main` function? Also make sure you indent all your code correctly; good indentation will make it much easier to spot this error.

Answer (score 1):

Remove semicolon in the first line.

Answer (score 1):

if this isnt a typo, you have a semicolon(;) on your first line of the code

```
   public int[][] fileRead(String fileName);
```

remove that

```
public int[][] fileRead(String fileName)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function definition should not have semi colon at end , please remove it , Follow the coding style as declaring the braces at the end of function definition line so you can avoid such syntax errors very easily here is the [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

As:

```
     public int[][] fileRead(String fileName);
```

Change To:

```
     public int[][] fileRead(String fileName){
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the semicolon after the method definition.

```
public int[][] fileRead(String fileName);
```

And you are missing `return` statement for your method.

Comment: The whole method does have a Return statement. Thanks

Comment: -1 its not declaration, it is method definition and he has not posted his whole method code.